# Заменить значение на отображаемое (добавить формат ячейки)

Tags: excel, vba

[фаил excel](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NR1PtCFMXXYv0toodz3WfuACyanDpjfd)Есть много значений в столбце. Ячейки с разными форматами.

Допустим, значение в ячейке 9, а выводится оно как *9С-228ТСП*, т.к. ячейка имеет формат `0"С-228ТСП"`. Похожих форматов очень много.

Как скопировать значения в таком виде, как они отображаются (число с текстом)?

Функция *ТЕКСТ* не подходит, так-как форматов очень много, в каждой ячейке свой

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Форматирование же сохраняется при копирование стандартным методом. Не понятно в чем загвоздка

Comment: Чтоб дальше работать с этой ячейкой, нужно чтоб она была текстом

Comment: Если как вариант сделать копию столбца, его форматировать уже, и с ним же работать?

Comment: Простите не понял. Даже допустим cntl+f не работает, потому что в ячейке "9" а не 9С-228ТСП. Ячейка со значением "9", отформатированна добавочным "С-228ТСП"

Comment: Данные нужно изменить на месте7 Перенести в другой диапазон? Произвести другие действия?

Comment: В любом месте, просто мне нужно каким-то образом получить такую же колонку, только с текстом 9С-228ТСП  а не 9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если все форматы имеют такую же структуру (*число"текст"*), выполнить небольшй макрос:

```
Sub ValueInFormat()
Dim rRng As Range
Dim i As Long
    With Worksheets("Лист1")
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rRng = .Range("B1:B" & i)
    End With

    For i = 1 To rRng.Rows.Count
        With rRng(i, 1)
            If .Value = "" Then .Value = .Value & Split(.NumberFormat & """", """")(1)
        End With
    Next i

    rRng.NumberFormat = "@"
    Set rRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Код изменит значения ячеек заполненного диапазона в столбце *B* и задаст текстовый формат ячейкам.

Немного доработать - исходные данные не будут меняться, результат запишется в отдельный диапазон:

```
Sub ValueInFormat()
Dim aF()
Dim rRng As Range
Dim i As Long
    With Worksheets("Лист1")
        i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rRng = .Range("B1:B" & i)
        aF = .Range("B1:B" & i).Value

        For i = 1 To UBound(aF)
            If aF(i, 1) <> Empty Then aF(i, 1) = aF(i, 1) & Split(rRng(i, 1).NumberFormat & """", """")(1)
        Next i

        .Range("D1").Resize(UBound(aF), 1).Value = aF
    End With

    Set rRng = Nothing
End Sub
```

Код разместить в общем модуле. Вход в редактор *VBA* - `Alt+F11`

Comment: aF(i, 1) = aF(i, 1) & Split(rRng(i, 1).NumberFormat, """")(1)  строка вызывает ошибку

Comment: Или обрабатываете не тот лист (в макросе указано имя "Лист1"), или в ячейке другой тип форматирования. При ошибке поставьте указатель над переменной i - покажет значение  переменной.  В данном случае это номер строки. Посмотрите форматирование ячейки в строке i

Comment: Показывает строку 415, там уже идет нормальные форматы ячеек, попробовал удалить все ниже 415 строки, все равно ошибку выдает, теперь на пустой ячейке. Добавил сам фаил в шапку.

Comment: Изменил строку кода (игнорирование пустых ячеек и обход ошибки при другом форматировании)